# How can I count the number of repeated elements/value in map?

Tags: c++

For example, how could I find the number of "59" ages? also "64"? The names are not necessary
in the outputs, and I only need the Age, and number of times it repeated. From here, it is 64->2 and 53->2 times. (Also, there is no integer that determines the number of rows.)

```
  Name         Age
{ XzbitYmay    64
  Bruce Watson 53
  Nim George   53
  Lee Harry    64
  Nim George   59 }
```

Comment: Please show your best effort, and ask a specific question about your attempt.

Comment: Do you want to count the occurrences of every age present in the map, or just one specific (and arbitrary) age?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;



int main() {

    unordered_map<int, size_t> counts;


    std::map<std::string, int> m = { 
        {"XzbitYmay",  64},  
        {"Bruce Watson",  53}, 
        {"Nim George",  53},
        {"Lee Harry",  64},
        {"Nim George",  59 }};

    for(const auto& kvp : m) {
        counts[kvp.second]++;
    }

    for(const auto& kvp: counts) {
        if(kvp.second > 0)
            std::cout << kvp.first << "->" << kvp.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Live example [here](https://ideone.com/WERYlA).